# AR.js aframe object show also without pointing marker

Tags: three.js, aframe, ar.js

In my AR project I use arjs with aframe to make my gltf object visibe when I point with my phone camera on my hiro pattern:

```
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.0.4/aframe.min.js"></script>
<!-- include ar.js for A-Frame -->
<script src="https://jeromeetienne.github.io/AR.js/aframe/build/aframe-ar.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-orbit-controls@1.2.0/dist/aframe-orbit-controls.min.js"></script> 

<body style='margin : 0px; overflow: hidden;'>
  <a-scene embedded arjs>
    <!-- define your gltf asset -->
    <!--This is for add a text-->
    <!--<a-text value="Hello, World!"></a-text>-->
    <!--This is for add an image-->
    <!--<a-image src="another-image.png"></a-image>-->
    <a-assets>
      <a-asset-item id="tree" src="models/gltf/manovella.gltf"></a-asset-item>
    </a-assets>
    <a-entity gltf-model="#tree" position="0 0 0" rotation="0 90 0" scale="10 10 10"></a-entity>

    <a-entity camera look-controls orbit-controls="target: 0 1.6 -0.5; minDistance: 0.5; maxDistance: 180; initialPosition: 0 5 15">
      <!-- define a camera which will move according to the marker position -->
      <a-marker-camera preset='hiro'></a-marker-camera>
    </a-entity>
  </a-scene>
</body>
```

when I point to my marker all was done, the problem is then also when I start my app without pointing to any market the object appears and when I no longer see the marker in the frame, the object remains on the screen.
How can I manage my gltf show/hide only related to my marker?

So many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your object should be inside your marker. Try to use this in your scene:

```
<a-assets>
  <a-asset-item id="tree" src="models/gltf/manovella.gltf"></a-asset-item>
</a-assets>
  <!-- define a camera which will move according to the marker position -->
  <a-marker-camera preset='hiro'><a-entity gltf-model="#tree" position="0 0 0" rotation="0 90 0" scale="10 10 10"></a-entity></a-marker-camera>
<a-entity camera look-controls orbit-controls="target: 0 1.6 -0.5; minDistance: 0.5; maxDistance: 180; initialPosition: 0 5 15"></a-entity>
```